# Windows 7: how to find which program this window belongs to so I can disable/uninstall it?

Tags: windows-7, windows, uninstall

After installing the drivers for Windows the following program is always open:

[image: annoying program]

I can't right-click it, when I hover over it it says nothing, and it's always on top of other windows. When minimized it also gets in the way.

I think it comes from the ASUS driver but not sure, any way I can find out without uninstalling everything?

Thanks to Doktoro Reichard's answer I found [this thread](http://linustechtips.com/main/topic/29578-get-rid-of-asus-ai-suite-widget/).

To remove the ASUS AI Suite 3 desktop gadget right-click on the ASUS Suite icon in the icon tray and deselect "ASUS Mini Bar".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Task Manager (Ctrl-Alt-Delete), look for Applications running, then you right click the application. Go to "Go to process" you should have the application name.

EDIT: Blessed Google Image Search, searched your pic and first result was the [ASUS driver page - AI Suite II / III](http://promos.asus.com/US/TCO/pages/UserExperience/AISuite.html). Seems like it is this, isn't it?

EDIT + UPDATE: Searched a little more, found [this](http://www.overclock.net/t/1139980/how-to-disable-ai-suite-from-startup#post_15277858) answer written by TwoCables at overclock.net. After reading it seems to be written for AI Suite II but it should work for III as well. Quoting the relevant parts:

> 1 - Open Task Scheduler (in Vista and 7, open the Start Menu, type task scheduler, and then press Enter)
>
> 2 - On the far left side, expand Task Scheduler Library
>
> 3 - Select "ASUS"
>
> 4 - In the middle, you'll see two Tasks named "ASUS AI Suite II Execute", and "ASUS DigiVRM Help"
>
> 5 - Right-click them and choose "Disable" (you can select both by holding down either Shift or Ctrl and left clicking them)
>
> 6 - Close Task Manager
>
> So now AI Suite II will no longer start with Windows! The best part is
>   that AI Suite II will not automatically undo these changes any time
>   you open it, so now it's just like any other program. You can also
>   Shut Down or Restart while AI Suite II is running, and it will still
>   not cause it to start with Windows.
>
> However, there are still a bunch of processes running in the
>   background! Fortunately, you can easily disable all of them and never
>   have to worry about it! Here's how:
>
> 1 - Open Services.msc (open the Start Menu, type services.msc, and then press Enter)
>
> 2 - Look for the following services:
>
> - ASUS Com Service
> - ASUS HM Com Service
> - ASUS System Control Service
>
> 3 - Change both "ASUS Com Service" and "ASUS HM Com Service" to Manual.
>
> 4 - Change "ASUS System Control Service" to Disabed.
>
> So now when you open AI Suite II, it will still be able to start both
>   "ASUS Com Service" and "ASUS HM Com Service" (both of these start up a
>   few other processes at the same time). I mean, if these were set to
>   Disabled, then you'd get an error.
>
> Note: every single process that gets started by these two services
>   will continue running even after completely exiting AI Suite II.
>   Fortunately, they do not automatically start with Windows! So if you
>   wanted to be in complete control and always stop them right after
>   exiting AI Suite II, then go into Services.msc, right-click the two
>   services we set to "manual", and then choose "Stop". Although, you'll
>   have to remember to do this every single time if you are a person like
>   me who likes to keep everything under control. hehe

Comment: Hi, it's not under applications.

Comment: Well, you "could" try to check under Processes. If it is an Asus driver, then it "should" have some name starting with asus*. If you think you found the culprit, try Ending Process, although I advise caution, as you might shut off essential parts of the system.

Comment: D'oh. Seems like you answered the last part. My update will be of use if you would want to disable permanently the application altogether.

Answer (score 2):

To directly answer the question in the topic (for posterity sake):

"How to find which program a window belongs to so I can disable/uninstall it?"

The excellent [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) is an alternative task manager. In it, there's a crosshair icon on it's toolbar. Click-hold and drag that icon to any window and it will hilite the process in it's task list.

While hilited, you can use the Process menu > Search Online menu entry for more info about that specific task. it basically just throws the executable name at google. Nonetheless, it's very handy.

Comment: (for posterity's sake) you could link to Process Explorer instead of sending all people that come by this to google. Guessing that this question is indeed worded at something like a Wiki page or a Q/A, except I would switch "this" for "any".

Comment: gaaaah... allow me to be lazy... ok fine. (= Linked.